# Treasury Direct requires Medallion for verification, how can I get my bank to do it?

Tags: united-states, treasury

I attempted to sign up for an account at Treasury Direct. Apparently they couldn't validate who I was based on the Address, Bank Account Number, Bank Routing Number, Social Security number, AND State issued ID. SO They sent me [form 5444](https://www.treasurydirect.gov/pdf/rs/acctauth.pdf) to fill out and return.

Near the bottom of the form it clearly says

> "ACCEPTABLE CERTIFICATIONS: Financial institution’s official seal or
>   stamp (such as corporate seal, signature guaranteed stamp, or
>   medallion stamp). (Notary certification is NOT acceptable.)"

So what do I do? I go to a bank to which I have a history with and asked them to medallion me. Their response you ask?

> "We don't just hand out medallion stamps. You need to be transferring
>   stocks or something in order to get that. We don't medallion forms for
>   Identification"

So I called my primary bank USAA (Which has no brick or mortar locations in my state) and spoke to checking, who had no clue what I was talking about then investments, who tried to sell me things (not T-bills though).

SO, my questions to you:

- Has anyone else had this issue?
- How have you fixed this issue?

Comment: It's funny that Treasury Direct requires a DNA sample and sworn affidavits from 832 immediate family members just to buy T-Bills, but the IRS will send out a refund to any yokel who can create a TurboTax account with a made up SSN and name.

Comment: Government efficiency

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a headache inducing circular argument with Treasury Direct phone support staff, I decided to take a low tech approach. I tried registering again with a different email. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I needed a medallion verification similar to this at some point, and my Credit Union gladly provided one (for a fee of, if I remember correctly, $10). However, they said that they only provide this service to members, i.e.: you need to have an account for a bank to do this for you.

From what I understand, it is pretty common in the financial world to trust financiers who already have a relationship with you to establish your identity, and the fact that your bank refuses to cooperate is surprising.

Comment: Huntington was VERY clear about them not being allowed to do it. USAA is a military bank. They have one branch in the entire world and it happens to be on the opposite end of the continent. I'm not sure what to do from here.

Comment: @AnthonyRussell check other local banks/credit unions, and if needed - open account in one just for this (or maybe move to it, if your bank is so uncooperative).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. TD suggested trying a broker also. I'm not sure how that would have played out